# How to convert JSON to Java class using Gson's fromJson method?

Tags: java, gson

I have a message in JSON and I want convert it to a Java object using the "fromJson" method of the Gson library.

How can I do this?

I have the message JSON in this format:

```json
{
   "desc":[
      {
         "name":"id",
         "desc":{
            "ip_arduino":"value",
            "id_house":"value",
            "house_address":"value"
         }
      },
      {
         "name":"P1",
         "desc":{
            "field":"panel1",
            "value":0
         }
      },
      {
         "name":"P2",
         "desc":{
            "field":"panel3",
            "value":0
         }
      },
      {
         "name":"P3",
         "desc":{
            "field":"panel3",
            "value":0
         }
      },
      {
         "name":"P4",
         "desc":{
            "field":"panel4",
            "value":0
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

I have tried this, but it does not work. I have printed some value, but it is null:

jsonDesc.java file

```java
public class jsonDesc {

    private ArrayList<Desc> desc = new ArrayList();
    
}
```

and Desc.java file

```java
public class Desc {
    String name;
    desc desc;

    desc1 desc1;

    public class desc{
       String ip_arduino;
       String id_house;
       String house_address;
    }

    public class desc1{
        String name;
        desc desc;
        public class desc{
            String field;
            String value;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have this in an object then it is simple as this

```
Desc desc = new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, Desc.class);
```

Also for creating class models don't waste time making your own... just use this: https://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Saves headache and time

Comment: thank you, I was looking for a tool like this

Comment: No problem, definitely comes in handy for me!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to read the JSON from a file and parse it into a Desc object:

```java
Gson gson = new Gson();
Reader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get("desc.json"));
Desc desc= gson.fromJson(reader,Desc.class);
reader.close();
```